# xcode duplicates build source files process

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, build-process, cocos2d-iphone

I am using the cocos2d library. when xcode builds, it builds twice as many source files as it needs to, i.e. 162 instead of the 81 that come with the cocos2d library.

this only happens when i build in release mode on the device, i.e. not device / debug nor simulator release / debug.

I have tried clean all targets to no avail.

I am using iOS4 with the latest version of the SDK.

Anyone know where to start looking for this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal.

When you build in Release mode, the compiler must compile each file for each architecture specified in the Build settings. If you use the Xcode template for an iPhone app, there are two architectures, armv6 and armv7, that get built.

When you're in Debug mode, it only builds the currently active architecture. This is also set in the Build settings with the appropriately named setting.

Comment: thanks for this. but it's odd the way it doesn't do it in simulator / release mode then, or is that normal also? 

Also, is it normal to get duplicate compiler warning messages, i.e. same warnings duplicated for the same files - forgot to mention that was happening.